# C# making a text box display what check boxes have been checked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox

Afternoon folks,

My question concerns check boxes and text boxes.

To give it context i am making a timetabling system that allows users to add timetable events to their own timetables and in order to select what times their event occurs, i have a series of check boxes.

I have 25 check boxes in all and i was wondering if i can make a text box (or label) display the name of the check box that is checked?

For example the user checks Monday at 9:15 and Friday at 2:15, my text box would display Monday 9:15 and Friday 2:15.

Thanks

Comment: 25 check boxes and 25 text boxes, or 25 check boxes and 1 text box ?

Comment: check boxes or radio buttons ?

Comment: I've got 25 check boxes and 1 text box, and the idea is that the user selects appropriate times based on the check boxes name (9:15,1:15 etc etc) Currently i've tried nested if statements when a button is clicked but i'm now thinking of just using the on checkchanged even as ElectricRouge has suggested. Thanks for all your help though!

Comment: @Rivaarn  Please consider marking an answer as a solution if it has helped you.

Comment: @ElectricRouge your answer is false, as it doesn't work if many checkboxes is checked. And you need to write 25 methods, one for each checkbox !

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to forums and posting as i normally hate them, but this is for my 3rd year project at uni so i needed a bit more help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event CheckedChanged. As you use many checkboxes, you can write only one method and use it for all checkboxes.

I recommand you to use a list of values to stock what you want to show in the textbox then work on it (in my example, I sort the data and concatene them).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<String> listData;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.listData = new List<String>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkBoxs_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox theCheckBoxChanged = sender as CheckBox;

        // verify the event is from a checkbox
        if (theCheckBoxChanged != null)
        {
            if (theCheckBoxChanged.Checked)
            {
                // add data
                this.listData.Add(theCheckBoxChanged.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                // remove data
                this.listData.Remove(theCheckBoxChanged.Text);
            }

            this.UpdateTextBox();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateTextBox()
    {
        // be carefull, you can't concatenate if there is no data.
        if (this.listData.Count > 0)
        {
            // sort and concatenate
            this.textBox1.Text = this.listData
                                     .OrderBy(s => s)
                                     .Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + " and " + s2);
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to assign the event `CheckedChanged` of all checkboxes to `checkBoxs_CheckedChanged`

Answer (score 3):

Do this in `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` event

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(checkBox1.Checked)  
       textBox1.Text = checkBox1.Text;
 }
```

Comment: so, you write 25 `checkboxXXX_checkedChanged()` ?

Comment: what if 2 checkboxes are checked ? `For example the user checks Monday at 9:15 and Friday at 2:15, my text box would display Monday 9:15 and Friday 2:15.`

Comment: @Xaruth So you are expecting me to do all the coding for him? I only showed him how to set textbox value when a checkbox is checked. How he implements it in his solution is upto him.

Comment: In case of multiple selection, then how to change this code

Answer (score 1):

I'd do some thing like this:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(checkBox1.Checked)  
   listbox1.items.add(checkBox1.Text);
}
```

In this way the date and time will get added to a list.
Personaly i think this way works beter as you can see all the dates you list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry cause I can't comment your post, @Rouge. I would like to add

```
if(checkBox1.Checked) { // your statement }
```

cause in your case I think the textBox will change its text even when it changes its state from checked to unchecked.

Comment: Never thought of it like that, and whne you put it that way it seems so obvious haha. Thanks guys